# How to show List in @OneToMany relation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm having an entity TechnicalStack and an entity Category, which an Category may have many TechnicalStack inside.

Here is my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "technical_stack")
public class TechnicalStack implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long ID;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;
    
    private String Question;
    
    @Column(columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR(MAX)") 
    private String Answer;
    
    private int Bookmark;
    
    private int CheatSheet;
}
```

and Category

```
@Entity
@Table(name="categories")
public class Category implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Set<TechnicalStack> techList = new HashSet<>();

    private String categoryName;
    private String description;
}
```

I'm only using normal JPA function, findAll, save, etc.

So, when I save an category item, like:

```
{
    "description" : "...",
    "categoryName" : "name1update",
    "techList": [{
        "question" : "ABC",
        "answer" : "XYZ"
    }]
}
```

when I already have some records in 2 table TechStack and Category, I want to view category, i'm having this by calling findAll()

```
`[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "techList": [],
        "categoryName": "name1update",
        "description": "..."
    }
]`
```

but, when I check technical stack record, i have like this:

```
`{
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "techList": [],
        "categoryName": null,
        "description": null
    },
    "id": 3,
    "question": "question11",
    "answer": "answer22",
    "bookmark": 0,
    "cheatSheet": 0
}`
```

Controller:

```
    @PostMapping("/category/viewAll")
public List<Category> viewAllCategory() {
    return repo.findAll();
}
```

TechnicalStack is working fine, but vice versa is not. The techList inside category shouldn't be empty.
How do i implement, so when the jpa call category by findAll(), I also got the techList?

I think i can do it by manually call the techList. That wouldn't be a problem. One query statement to call the category id, and one query to call the technical stack IN the list just called. But I don't think that is fully used JPA/Hibernate.

Thank you

Comment: You are using Lazy Fetch for your list of techList. So it won't come with parent entity. You would rather need to use Eager Fetch or make seperate query and populate object post that.

Comment: I tried that. But still it still the same. Beside, i'm using RestController, like:  @PostMapping("/category/viewAll")
 public List<Category> viewAllCategory() {
  return repo.findAll();
which the JSON parse will make it run

Comment: Would you please share your complete code? It's tough to find the issue with available info.

Comment: that's pretty much everything. I only have 2 entity, and 1 controller which run categoryRepository.findAll

Comment: I don't see controller here

Comment: @PostMapping("/category/viewAll") 
public List<Category> viewAllCategory() 
{ return repo.findAll();}
Ah, i post it in the last comment

Comment: Please add that complete code in question rather, in order to help you better.

Comment: I just did. I dont think the jpa function only need to be posted

Comment: You have a bidirectional relationship that is controlled from the TechnicalStack side - this means for the relationship to be persisted in the database, the Posted TechnicalStack MUST have its category reference set. The JSON you have doesn't set it, and it isn't likely being set in your controllers - that would be the place to do it. When you take in a Category, go through its list of TechnicalStack and make sure each reference 'this' category. You WILL get a stack overflow error once you do this though because you do not have mechanisms to tell JSON how to handle the circular reference

Comment: Try @JSONIgnore and look for questions on circular references in JSON

Comment: I thought @OneToMany mean the category should be the one who controll the technicalStack?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is by using Spring Data JPA Projection. In your spring data JPA Repository, define the following method:

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {
@Query("select c from Category c")
List<CategoryWithTechList> findAllWithTechList();
}
```

And here is how the CategoryWithTechList projection will look like:

```
import java.util.Set;

public interface CategoryWithTechList {
    Long getId();

    String getCategoryName();

    String getDescription();

    Set<TechnicalStackInfo> getTechList();
    
    interface TechnicalStackInfo {
        Long getID();

        String getQuestion();

        String getAnswer();

        int getBookmark();

        int getCheatSheet();
    }
}
```

The get endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/category/viewAll")
public List<CategoryWithTechList> viewAllCategory() {
    return categoryRepository.findAllWithTechList();
}
```

Returned result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "techList": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "question": "1",
        "bookmark": 1,
        "cheatSheet": 1,
        "answer": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "question": "1",
        "bookmark": 1,
        "cheatSheet": 1,
        "answer": "1"
      }
    ],
    "categoryName": "Cat1",
    "description": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "techList": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "question": "2",
        "bookmark": 2,
        "cheatSheet": 2,
        "answer": "2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "question": "2",
        "bookmark": 2,
        "cheatSheet": 2,
        "answer": "2"
      }
    ],
    "categoryName": "Cat2",
    "description": "2"
  },
]
```

Btw, I also recond you keep all the field names in camelCase in your JPA Entities.